# How to generate rmarkdown report in Shiny as a desktop application

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

according to:
[Locally installed Shiny app](http://oddhypothesis.blogspot.de/2014/04/deploying-self-contained-r-apps-to.html)
I developed a Shiny application which can be distributed as a folder with a runscript and R-portable inside.

Now I implemented an export button in the shiny app, which generates a pdf file through rmarkdown. Running the shiny app from rstudio works.
But running the app in the folder with runscript, the pdf export does not work.

I think I also need RStudio portable and miktex portable inside the folder, but I do not know how to link the `render` function in `rmarkdown` package to this RStudio and how does RStudio know where the miktex executable is?

I can not install RStudio and miktex locally on the other machines, so I have to distribute it with the Shiny app.

Thanks for helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem.
I copied the `pandoc` folder from RStudio and `miktex portable` into the main folder of my desktop app.
Second, I wrote the following into the `RProfile.site` in R-Portable (`RPortable/App/R-Portable/etc/RProfile.site`):

`Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/bin/server",sep=";","../pandoc/","../miktex/miktex/bin/"))`

Now it runs on different machines. Only the Java path has to be changed eventually on another machine.

Bests